# Get type of transaction for input dataset

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, incremental

I'm working with an incremental dataset. Sometimes my input switches from an update transaction to a snapshot transaction. I want to know the type of my input transaction for my build because my transformation depends on the input type.

I used the `count()` of dataframe which is working but it's not optimized and it's not the best way. `ctx.isincremental` is about the current job and not the input.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `is_incremental` boolean.

Something like:

```
def compute(ctx, ...):
    ctx.is_incremental == true:
        # Your logic if is incremental
    else:
        # Your logic is snapshot
```

See https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/incremental-reference/index.html#important-information

--- to answer to comment

Your current transform **will** snapshot if your upstream dataset snapshots **regardless** of schema changes. Your current transform **won't** snapshots if this particular input/upstream is whitelisted in the "[snapshot_input](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/incremental-reference/index.html#snapshot-inputs)" of your incremental decorator.

That being said, your questions is valid if your input is in the snapshot_input list AND sometimes it run as `snapshot`" and sometimes as `update` AND you need to differentiate in the code what happens with each type.

In Java transforms, you can use the [`modificationType()`](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-java/incremental-transforms/index.html/#read-the-input) but I don't think there is an equivalent method in python.

You can however read your dataframe "as you want" (only the incremental part, the whole dataset) with the [read_modes](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/incremental-reference/index.html#incrementaltransforminput), which should be enough to cover most (all?) use-cases.

Might you describe what/why you are trying to achieve this to help you more ?

Comment: is_incremental as i said it's for the current job, if input change from update to snapshot my job will continue to run in incremantal if they are no changes in schema, i want to know to type of transaction of my input, i njava it's possible by read range but python i don't know

Comment: Added a few notes in my answer as it is a bit too long for a comment.
If you can describe your use-case/what you are trying to achieve more precisely it would help to provide a better answer, but indeed I don't think modificationType exists in Pyton.